# Is there a super user account?

Tags: private-blockchain

Basically I am looking at controlling the user account creation.  Only super user account shall be allow creating/deleting the user accounts.  Is this possible in Ethereum?

Answer (score 2):

Creating an Ethereum address requires no connection to the network, it's a 100% client-side process. You can't stop people from doing it.

You can however create a whitelist of addresses that are allowed to submit transactions to your network.

Comment: By 'your network' I assume Jesse is referring to smart contracts superficially deployed on the Ethereum network.

Comment: or a node / nodes

Comment: @ad1s The question is tagged 'private-blockchain'

Comment: Thank you, whitelist approach make sense to control user accounts in the private chain.